# How can I get the checked status of a checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a gridview parameter in my asp.net program as follows:

Name: `row.Cells[5].Controls[0]`

Value: `(Text="" Checked=true)`

type: `System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox`

How can I get the Checked status of such parameter?

Answer (score 0):

It's been quite a while since I worked on GridView. Did you try this?

> ```
> protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)            
> {   
>    var mycheckbox = (CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[5].Controls[0];
>    var status = mycheckbox.checked;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here...

```
(CType(gridview.Rows(0).Cells(5).Controls(0), CheckBox).Checked)
```

Comment: Add some explanation and not just a snippet

Answer (score 0):

If you have specified id for that control then you can use the `FindControl` method, or else you can go ahead with the Controls[0]. Anyway You have to try something like this:

```
CheckBox chkBox = row.Cells[5].FindControl("checkBoxId") as CheckBox;
if (chkBox.Checked)
{
   // given checkbox is checked
}
else
{
  // it is not checked
}
```

Or like this:

```
CheckBox chkBox = row.Cells[5].Controls[0] as CheckBox;
if (chkBox.Checked)
{
   // given checkbox is checked
}
else
{
  // it is not checked
}
```